# Extracting multiple images from a single image in CS6

Tags: cs6, selections

I'm trying to make a copy of a logo that I can add some Styles to.  The logo:

[image]

So, I click on the Quick Selection tool and grab the central image.  Everything looks great.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to grab the gray areas around it.  If I click the Quick Selection tool again, it simply unselects what I previously selected and starts selecting the new area.

How do I get the Quick Selection tool to select multiple areas of the same image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Photoshop, try holding down Shift

Comment: Perfect!  Probably a n00b question, but I'm definitely a n00b with CS6.  :o)